# Assigning field inside javascript class from ajax

Tags: javascript

I have code like this:

```
class Korisnik
{
    constructor(korisnikId)
    {
        this.KORISNIKID = korisnikId;
        this.IME = "";
        this.UNIQUE_KEY = "";

        this.Initialize();
    }

    Initialize(kid)
    {
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "../Php/Korisnik_Get.php",
           data: {"korisnikId" : this.KORISNIKID},
           success: function(result)
           {
               var arr = result.split('|');
               this.IME = arr[0];
               this.UNIQUE_KEY = arr[1];
           }
        });
    }

    get naziv()
    {
        alert("IME: " + this.IME); //Undefined
        return this.IME;
    }
}
```

I initialize this class as `let myClass = new Korisnik(1);`

When I try to get `naziv()` It returns nothing. I have tested it and when I `alert` `this.IME` from inside `success` code it has value but outside it doesn't. I have read and tried from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-cal) but anything from there is not working for some reason. What to do?

Comment: `this` inside the `$.ajax` success callback isn't what `this` is outside it. See the linked questions for answers (in this case: use an arrow function or `bind`).

Answer (score -1):

Js getters aren't functions, so you need to access it as `myClass.naziv`

The other problem you have is that your `success` function isn't running in the same *scope* as the rest of your function.

You can use a fat-arrow function to ensure you have the right scope.

```
       success: result =>
       {
           var arr = result.split('|');
           this.IME = arr[0];
           this.UNIQUE_KEY = arr[1];
       }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Preferably leave feedback as to why you're downvoting